# why in-built prolog predicates are written with a slash(/)

Tags: prolog, predicate

for example: `aggregate_all/3` , `findall/3`, `aggregate/4` and so on.
What is the difference between `aggregate/3` and `aggregate/4`.

Comment: The slash indicates "arity" (which means the number of arguments). It makes a difference because a predicate but the same name but a different arity is essentially a different predicate. So, for example, there are two versions of the `aggregate` predicate. One is `aggregate/3` which accepts 3 arguments, and the other is `aggregate/4` which accepts 4 arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The number is the so-called **arity** of the predicate and indicates the number of *arguments* of the predicate.

This is useful because there are often several variants of predicates that share the same name, but differ in their number of arguments.

Examples: `findall/3` and `findall/4`, `append/3` and `append/2` etc.

You also often see the notation `(Pred)/2`. Example: `(#=)/2`.This is because `#=` (for example) is also an infix **operator**, and the parentheses turn `(#=)/2` into a valid Prolog term.

Answer (score 1):

The slash `(/)` symbol is not used only in built in predicates but in all predicates ant it states the number of parameters (**arity)** of the predicate for example `aggregate/3` is a predicate with 3 parameters while `aggregate/4` is a predicate with 4 parameters.